# Sonata Admin sonata_type_collection delete button does not display

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I wan't to make embed form with sonata_type_collection,

My model is ok and  in my embed form i cant add line  but i have a probleme the delete button for the embed form  does not display .

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
    ->add('date', 'datetime')
    ->add('title', 'text')
    ->add('author', 'text')
    ->add('content', 'textarea')
    ->add('images', 'sonata_type_collection', [

        'required' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
    ], [
        'edit' => 'inline',
        'inline' => 'table',
        'sortable' => 'position',

    ]);
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: you should have something like a checkbox and when you check it and do an update it will be deleted.

Comment: thank's i check and do  update but the line is not delete

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the user does not have DELETE permission

> If you are using the sonata.admin.security.handler.role, you must set, at least, the CREATE permission to the Admin of the relation, to be able to add more rows to the collection. In order to delete rows, you must set the DELETE permission. For more infos about permissions, check the Security page.

[Sonata\Form\Type\CollectionType](https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/4.x/reference/form_types/#sonata-form-type-collectiontype)

Comment: I was looking for something else, but when I saw the question I remembered this warning